# Boolean Algebra: making a proof assistance

Tags: boolean-algebra

So far i've tried all the identities my teacher gave us and keep getting stuck

I have to prove that x'y' + y = x' + xy using boolean algebra identities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x'y'+y=x'y'+y(x+x')\text{ as }x+x'=1$$

$$=x'y'+xy+x'y=xy+x'(y'+y)=\cdots$$

We can also write $1=1+x'$ to find $$x'y'+y=x'y'+y(1+x')=\cdots=x'+y$$